# Sync base site login and Wordpress login for account management

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

Please bear with me as I am new to Wordpress.

I have a base site that allows the purchase of products using unique platform currency.
Users can register on the website, but if they want to purchase any of the content, they first need to purchase credits.
I have a Wordpress site that utilises a WooCommerce store (StoreFront), where these credits can be purchased. Once the user purchases credits on the Wordpress site, the amount of credits purchased is written to the base site database.

On the Wordpress site, there is an account management page that allows users to track orders, information, and more. They can also add cards to checkout quickly.

Is there a way to link the account registration on the base site and the Wordpress site. I want the users to be able to have the benefit of both modules, without having to register twice.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you a developer who has received this as a task, or a business making the ask?  I only ask because SO is only really suitable for solving issues with code or existing integrations.  Designing a system by which two separate websites could be integrated, if it is at all possible, would be something you'd have to pay a lot of money for.

Comment: Perhaps comes in handy: [https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/53082/login-in-wordpress-using-external-database-data](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/53082/login-in-wordpress-using-external-database-data)